# About serialize the object having generic type in WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, generics

I implemented a generic way to get the object by id from Entities defined in Entity Framework.

But the problem is the object I got has a very weird type like this

> {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MyEntity_C71732021C3A9D6A58BDB6087D29E98CFDE09DA9D53AF0892AFB7918AEF7E61F}

And WCF will fail when serialize this object as the type of MyEntity.

How to make the generic type to be the specific type I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Entity Framework 4.0 POCO objects. If that's the case, MSDN has a great walk-through on how to get things working:

[Walkthrough: Serialize POCO Proxies with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx)

Also take a look at:

[Working with POCO Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) (pay close attention to the Serializing POCO Proxies section)

Comment: I think the problem is how to convert the type from MyEntity_C71732021C3A9D6A58BDB6087D29E98CFDE09DA9D53AF0892AFB7918AEF7E61F to MyEntity.

Comment: @sza - That's what the article covers! It creates a new attribute that handles the resolution for you.

Comment: thank you. hmm, but i still got the error and type is not converted

Comment: Pay close attention to step 13 in **To create and configure the WCF project**. Make sure you disabled lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I added the decorator ApplyDataContractResolver and disabled the lazy loading.